# Spark structured streaming - error while storing data into Azure datalake gen1

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I got stuck in one problem and currently trying to find out the solution. 
This problem is related to store the streaming data output to Azure Datalake. Below is the exception that I am getting while storing data

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.InvalidPathException: Invalid path name Wrong FS: adl://<azure-data-lake>.azuredatalakestore.net/eventstore/_spark_metadata, expected: adl://<azure-data-lake>.azuredatalakestore.net/
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.checkPath(AbstractFileSystem.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.getFileStatus(DelegateToFileSystem.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$14.next(FileContext.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$14.next(FileContext.java:1116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileStatus(FileContext.java:1116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.exists(FileContext.java:1581)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog$FileContextManager.exists(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.<init>(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.<init>(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSinkLog.<init>(FileStreamSinkLog.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.<init>(FileStreamSink.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSink(DataSource.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:293)
```

Below are my pom dependencies

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-eventhubs-spark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-eventhubs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-data-lake-store-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-eventhubs-eph</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help regarding to this will be appreciated.

Comment: If possible, can you include pseudo spark code? at least that write dataframe code

Comment: How do you `writeStream`? What kind of file sink do you use? Does this happen at the very beginning of the streaming query? What's your `checkpointLocation` option?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to resolve the issue by adding the appropriate maven dependencies.

The dependencies that I used are

1. hadoop-common - v3.8.1
2. azure-data-lake-store-sdk - v2.3.7
3. hadoop-azure-datalake v3.2.1

Hope this will help others to resolve this kind of issue.

Thanks
Avinash